# CATransition animation taking long time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, catransition

I added animation to push one controller to another controller.here is my code to push view.this animation is taking 2 second in iPhone 5S and taking 5 seconds in iPhone 5.i am not able to figure out what is exact issue.i want this animation for 1 second.here is my code.

```
 DetailVC *detailObj = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:nil];
 detailObj.dataGift = data;


        detailObj.view.transform =  CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
                             transition.duration = 0.75;
                             transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
                             transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
                             [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailObj animated:false];

                             detailObj.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
      });
```

Comment: You have one block `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0` and inside that `CATransition` which is taking 0.75 that should be reason for this

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya can you provide full code? if it works than i can upvote

Comment: Remove the transition code from `animateWithDuration:` body.  Don't need two animations here.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing animation inside animation block so your duration is increased

Replace your code with

```
 DetailVC *detailObj = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailVC" bundle:nil];
 detailObj.dataGift = data;
 detailObj.view.transform =  CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);


CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.75;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailObj animated:false];

detailObj.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
```

And make sure you perform that in Main Queue

Hope it is helpful

Comment: You should put it in main thread. All your UI should be in Main thread

Comment: i think         detailObj.view.transform =  CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);
missing in your answer

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Thanks for point it out. will update with relevant code

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Alternate solution would be a Transition delegate a good example https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/ You can customise    your animation

Comment: thanks for link,but code is not working.no effect of animation

Comment: Try to add/replace this lines     `transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];`

Comment: No effect in animation.i think animation block should be there

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Trust me you don't need that.  Just try this code with other view controller it should work

Comment: Ok let me check in other screen

Comment: You are right.working good in other screen.why taking time in perticular screen

Comment: @KrutarthPatel are you performing any heavy task on  DetailVC view did load method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167137/discussion-between-krutarth-patel-and-prashant-tukadiya).

Answer (score 0):

issue was in home detail screen,heavy task was happening in viewdidload.i check line by line,commenting each line in view didload which activity is taking more time.and i put time consuming activity in main thread and my issue is resolved.

here is my code of animation

```
 gameDetailObj.view.transform =  CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{

                             [self.navigationController pushViewControllerSafetly:gameDetailObj animated:NO];

                             gameDetailObj.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         }];
```